# How to push up text in CSS?

Tags: html, css

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/gNkKx/

I am trying to push up the text in a `div` by 50%, and I tried

```
padding-bottom: 50px; /*div is 100px high*/
```

But it does not work.

```
padding-top: -50px;
```

This does not work too. Any work-around?

Comment: `line-height:0px;` pushes it up some.

Comment: @sachleen - It does, but it is not 50px up...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`line-height:0px;` pushes it up some, but I don't know how much and it's apparently not 50px as you want.

You can wrap the element in another container and position it like so:

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">龍</div>
</div>
```

CSS (only showing modifications from your style)

```
.container{
    position: relative;
}
.block {
  position: absolute;
  top: -50px;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/gNkKx/4/)

Comment: Wrapping another `div` sure will solve it, but it will also create more mess in the HTML. I will go with the `line-height` one if there is no other method.

Comment: Instead of requiring an outer block and absolute positioning, the simpler solution is a single relative element, eg: `hello <span style="position:relative; top:-5px;">there</span>!`

Answer (score 1):

IF you are trying to center the text within the boxes, try the following:

```
div.block {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
   font-size: 80px;
    line-height: 80px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}​
```

Comment: I think he wants to push it up so the top half of the character is not visible. The first box shows how to make the bottom half invisible, but he can't figure out how to push the character up in the second box.

Comment: Sachleen is right. I am making something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/YVHBy/

Comment: @Derek understood. Thanks for following up. Your original question wasn't clear and I made a few assumptions :)

Answer (score 1):

A slightly cleaner solution: (building off of Sachleen's)

HTML:

```
<div class="move-me-up">
    <p>Some text</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.move-me-up {
    position: relative; 
    top: -50px;
}
```

This will move the text up 50 pixels on the screen, while only requiring one div!

Answer (score -1):

Try raising the text up with inline-block. Use a border to see where you are. By doing this you can see where margin-top can be adjusted up and how large it is.

```
<div style='display:inline-block;margin-top:-30px; border: 1px solid pink;'>
    <font style='color:green;'>today </font>
</div>
```